# Can I export a Canvas to an image in java?

Tags: java, image

I think I'll need a buffered Image and to use a ImageOutputStream. Sorry I'm clueless, hence the lack of info here. I'm hoping for a solve-all magic method.

Comment: This is the third millennium, use Swing (e.g. `JComponent`/`paintComponent(Graphics)` rather than `Canvas`/`paint(Graphics)`).

Answer (score 1):

Canvas to BufferedImage:

```
Canvas c = ...
BufferedImage im = ...
Graphics g = im.getGraphics();
c.paint(g);
```

BufferedImage to Canvas: in paint(Graphics g) method call:

```
g.drawImage(im, 0, 0, null);
```

Answer (score -1):

See [`ImageIO.write(RenderedImage,String,ImageOutputStream)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write%28java.awt.image.RenderedImage,%20java.lang.String,%20javax.imageio.stream.ImageOutputStream%29).